# Unity & glTFast - Can't load my GLTF file with LoadGltfBinary function

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, gltf

I am using Unity with the package glTFast.

I have an issue when trying to load a GLTF file. Here is the code :

```
public async void SetModel(string path) {
  if (!File.Exists(path)) {
      Debug($"File does not exist: {path}");
  }

  byte[] fileData;
  try {
      fileData = File.ReadAllBytes(path);
  } catch (IOException ex) {
      Debug($"Error reading file: {ex.Message}");
      return ;
  }

  Debug(fileData.Length.ToString());

  var gltf = new GltfImport();
  bool success = await gltf.LoadGltfBinary(
      fileData,
      new System.Uri(path)
  );
  if (success) {
      Debug("SUCCESS GLTF");
      var mainScene = await gltf.InstantiateMainSceneAsync(ArPrefab.transform);
  } else {
      Debug("FAIL GLTF");
  }
}
```

The success boolean will always be false although fileDataLenghtToString() is never equal to zero so I successfully load something in my byte[].

These are the files I am trying to load :

https://github.com/atteneder/glTFast/files/10869758/gltf.zip

glTFast version : 5.0.0

Unity Editor version : 2022.1.7f1

Platform: Android

Thanks for your help!!

**EDIT :**

I could make it work with :

```
bool success = await gltf.Load(
      fileData,
      new System.Uri(path)
);
```

instead of :

```
bool success = await gltf.LoadGltfBinary(
      fileData,
      new System.Uri(path)
  );
```

Here is the full code :

```
    public async void SetModel(string path) {
      if (!File.Exists(path)) {
          Debug($"File does not exist: {path}");
      }

      var gltf = new GltfImport();
      bool success = await gltf.Load(path);
      if (success) {
          Debug("SUCCESS GLTF");
          try {
            GameObject root = new GameObject("test");
            gltf.InstantiateMainScene(root.transform);
          } catch (Exception e) {
            Debug(e.ToString());
          }
      } else {
          Debug("FAIL GLTF");
      }
    }
```